# CSS unicode trigger character not working with Safari + other Apple products

Tags: css, unicode, safari, wordpress

I'm using a Wordpress plugin called collapse-o-matic on this website: [antiskrid.dk](http://www.antiskrid.dk/).

I've replaced the default "trigger" background-image for expanding/collapsing with a CSS Unicode graphic shape, and it shows up nice and clear in all browsers on every device I've got my hands on.

My problem is, that the trigger doesn't work in Safari on the PC, Safari + Chrome on the iPad and the default Android browser.

The trigger works with Chrome for Android and Safari on iPhone 5 though.

The original CSS looks like this:

```
.collapseomatic {
background-image: url(images/arrow-down.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 0 0 10px 16px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.colomat-close {
background-image: url(images/arrow-up.png);
}
```

This of course works in all browers on all platforms.

The problem occurs when I'm using my modified CSS:

```
.collapseomatic {
background-image: none;
padding:0;
}
.collapseomatic:after {
content:"\25BC";
}
.colomat-close {
background-image: none;
}
.colomat-close:after {
content:"\25B2";
}
```

I've tried a lot of workarounds, but without any luck, and I really want to make this work without a background image.

Any suggestions why this is happening and what to do to make it function proberly?

Comment: “Not working” is not a problem description. Specify what is expected in which part of a page and what happens instead. The page mentioned shows the special character OK on Safari on Windows, but the *functionality* is missing. This probably has nothing to do with “unicode trigger”. You should reduce the problem to a simple case instead of asking others to debug your site.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela

I agree with you. I could have worded it better, but the problem still exists regardless of the formulation. I will remember to be more specific next time I ask a question.
In spite of this, do you have a suggestion for what could be wrong? Or do you think I should open a new, more precise question?

Thank you!

Comment: You can edit the question to provide a description of the problem, but it is probably better to delete it and ask a new question.